# boost shared_ptr factory function

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I'm pretty new to the world of pointers and have run into a problem in my code.  I have a factory class that spits out shared_ptr's.  "Entity" is the base class for any type of shared_ptr that gets created from this method.

If I overwrite the pointer in the get_entity method, everything seems to work.  If i overwrite the pointer in the get_pointer method it doesn't.

```
// 
// typedef boost::shared_ptr<Entity> EntityPtr;

Entity::EntityPtr EntityFactory::get_entity(int type) {

    // My default pointer if everything else falls through
    Entity::EntityPtr e = boost::make_shared<Entity>(type);
    std::cout << e->get_type() << std::endl; // Entity

    switch (type) {
    case 1:
        // This works
        e = boost::make_shared<TextEntity>(type);
        std::cout << e->get_type() << std::endl; // TextEntity
        break;
    case 2:
        // This doesn't work
        get_pointer(e, type);
        std::cout << e->get_type() << std::endl; // Entity
        break;
    }

    return e;

}

// This function can (possibly) overwrite the passed-in pointer
void EntityFactory::get_pointer(Entity::EntityPtr e, int type) {

    // ...

    e = boost::make_shared<TextEntity>(type);

    // ...
}
```

My reasons for passing "e" into the get_pointer method was because i don't always need to modify the pointer.  In some cases get_pointer finishes without modifying the pointer at all.

I'm hoping someone can help shed some light on what i'm doing wrong here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty darn confusuled about wtf you're trying to do since you pass in integers to make_shared.

Your problem may be solved by accepting a reference to `Entity::EntityPtr` in `get_pointer`.

Comment: The constructor for my Entity and TextEntity clases both take an integer argument. That's why i'm passing it in to make_shared.  I added the reference and it worked!! Care to explain how my way was flawed?  I was always under the assumption that a reference to a shared_ptr was a no-no.

Comment: First, flawed assumption; don't know where you got it.  Second, your version was passing the pointer by value.  Setting that value with `e=` is all well and good, but the calling entity would never hear about it.  As with all things, if you want the change made to the parameter within the function to effect the variable used as the parameter, you need to take by reference.  This is true also of pointers and shared pointers.